# How to setup integration runtime for SAP ABAP in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, abap

How to create SAP ABAP connection setup in Azure Datafactory so that the Dataset can point to this Linked service

Comment: Stack Overflow is a help site for programming questions. Please have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Create a linked service to an SAP table using UI

**Step1:** Create Azure data factory resource and click on Dataset  New dataset

[image]

**Step2:**  Now type sap and select SAP Table

[image]

**Step3:** Now create New Linked Service

[image]

After above step you can follow this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#connector-configuration-details) for Connector configuration details.