# How to connect to SAP ECC (on Linux server) from Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sap-erp

How to connect to SAP ECC (on Linux server) from Azure Data Factory? In Datafactory under linked service I do see SAP ECC data store but it appears I have to use self hosted integration runtime.

Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Check these docs [Connect to and manage an SAP ECC source](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/purview/register-scan-sapecc-source.md)  [Copy data from SAP ECC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-sap-ecc.md)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real time Data Extraction from SAP ECC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73703771/real-time-data-extraction-from-sap-ecc)

Comment: also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008996/how-to-setup-integration-runtime-for-sap-abap-in-azure-datafactory/71013773#71013773